# Sending associative array as function parameter to SOAP in C#

Tags: c#, php, generics, soap, dictionary

In php it looks simple like this:

```
$client->map(array("abc" => "def", "zxc" => "vbn"));
```

function is defined as:

```
function map($data) {
```

The main problem is none of c# generics is serializable so I can't send that type of array in any way. After some days of hard thinking I'm out of ideas
How to?

Comment: What is the method signature or SOAP packet expected by the C# endpoint?

Comment: Generics in c# are serializable, but you need to use the KnownType attribute.  Dictionaries on the otherhand are not readily serializable.